# Prove that there are three real numbers a and b and c so that: $(\forall x\ne -1/2)\frac{6x^2+7x-3}{2x+1}=ax+b+\frac{c}{2x+1}$

Tags: calculus

1) Prove that there are three real numbers a and b and c so that: $(\forall x\ne -1/2)\frac{6x^2+7x-3}{2x+1}=ax+b+\frac{c}{2x+1}$

[[Addition: this question 1) is related to this question 2):

Conclude from 1) the value of this integral: $\int_0^1\frac{6x^2+7x-3}{2x+1}dx$]]

I never seen question like this in my life, how can we ever prove this? (I'm talking about 1) )

Thank you!!

Comment: Reduce the RHS to the same denominator and identify the coefficients of the numerator.

Comment: What? What is RHS? I didn't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Comment: $6x^2+7x-3=(2x+1)(3x+2)-5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

We have

$$ax+b+\frac{c}{2x+1}=\frac{(ax+b)(2x+1)+c}{2x+1}=\frac{2ax^2+(a+2b)x+b+c}{2x+1}=\frac{6x^2+7x-3}{2x+1}$$
so what's the value of $a,b$ and $c$?

Comment: I still don't know :(

Comment: The polynomial $2ax^2+(a+2b)x+b+c$ is equal to $6x^2+7x-3$ so the coefficient of $x^2$: $2a=6$ and the coefficient of $x$: $a+2b=7$ and the constant $b+c=-3$. Solve these equations.

Comment: AH! Thank you! Now I understand! :)

Comment: But how can it help me to solve question 2) please?

Comment: Calculate the integral using the expression on the right.

Comment: So I first have to find value for a and b and c then I use the expression on the right and then I try to find the integral? Are those the correct steps? Thank you one more time.

Comment: Yes these are the correct steps!

Comment: Many thanks! this helps a lot!!!

Comment: You're welcome.